# Selendroid - ANDROID_HOME not found even after setting it

Tags: android, automation, mobile-website, selendroid

I am trying to run [Selendroid](http://selendroid.io/) test for mobile website but as I run my test I get exception saying:

```
    May 19, 2014 11:48:59 AM io.selendroid.SelendroidLauncher launchServer
INFO: Starting selendroid-server port 4444
May 19, 2014 11:48:59 AM io.selendroid.SelendroidLauncher launchServer
SEVERE: Error occurred while building server: io.selendroid.exceptions.SelendroidException: Environment variable 'ANDROID_HOME' was not found!
java.lang.RuntimeException: io.selendroid.exceptions.SelendroidException: Environment variable 'ANDROID_HOME' was not found!
    at io.selendroid.server.model.SelendroidStandaloneDriver.initApplicationsUnderTest(SelendroidStandaloneDriver.java:142)
    at io.selendroid.server.model.SelendroidStandaloneDriver.<init>(SelendroidStandaloneDriver.java:80)
    at io.selendroid.server.SelendroidStandaloneServer.initializeSelendroidServer(SelendroidStandaloneServer.java:91)
    at io.selendroid.server.SelendroidStandaloneServer.<init>(SelendroidStandaloneServer.java:65)
    at io.selendroid.SelendroidLauncher.launchServer(SelendroidLauncher.java:49)
    at io.selendroid.SelendroidLauncher.launchSelendroid(SelendroidLauncher.java:73)
    at com.pb.crawler.MobileWebTest.startSelendroidServer(MobileWebTest.java:86)
    at com.pb.crawler.MobileWebTest.main(MobileWebTest.java:27)
Caused by: io.selendroid.exceptions.SelendroidException: Environment variable 'ANDROID_HOME' was not found!
    at io.selendroid.android.AndroidSdk.androidHome(AndroidSdk.java:97)
    at io.selendroid.android.AndroidSdk.platformToolsHome(AndroidSdk.java:86)
    at io.selendroid.android.AndroidSdk.aapt(AndroidSdk.java:39)
    at io.selendroid.android.impl.DefaultAndroidApp.deleteFileFromWithinApk(DefaultAndroidApp.java:102)
    at io.selendroid.builder.SelendroidServerBuilder.deleteFileFromAppSilently(SelendroidServerBuilder.java:116)
    at io.selendroid.builder.SelendroidServerBuilder.resignApp(SelendroidServerBuilder.java:125)
    at io.selendroid.server.model.SelendroidStandaloneDriver.initApplicationsUnderTest(SelendroidStandaloneDriver.java:138)
    ... 7 more
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.RuntimeException: io.selendroid.exceptions.SelendroidException: Environment variable 'ANDROID_HOME' was not found!
    at io.selendroid.server.model.SelendroidStandaloneDriver.initApplicationsUnderTest(SelendroidStandaloneDriver.java:142)
    at io.selendroid.server.model.SelendroidStandaloneDriver.<init>(SelendroidStandaloneDriver.java:80)
    at io.selendroid.server.SelendroidStandaloneServer.initializeSelendroidServer(SelendroidStandaloneServer.java:91)
    at io.selendroid.server.SelendroidStandaloneServer.<init>(SelendroidStandaloneServer.java:65)
    at io.selendroid.SelendroidLauncher.launchServer(SelendroidLauncher.java:49)
    at io.selendroid.SelendroidLauncher.launchSelendroid(SelendroidLauncher.java:73)
    at com.pb.crawler.MobileWebTest.startSelendroidServer(MobileWebTest.java:86)
    at com.pb.crawler.MobileWebTest.main(MobileWebTest.java:27)
Caused by: io.selendroid.exceptions.SelendroidException: Environment variable 'ANDROID_HOME' was not found!
    at io.selendroid.android.AndroidSdk.androidHome(AndroidSdk.java:97)
    at io.selendroid.android.AndroidSdk.platformToolsHome(AndroidSdk.java:86)
    at io.selendroid.android.AndroidSdk.aapt(AndroidSdk.java:39)
    at io.selendroid.android.impl.DefaultAndroidApp.deleteFileFromWithinApk(DefaultAndroidApp.java:102)
    at io.selendroid.builder.SelendroidServerBuilder.deleteFileFromAppSilently(SelendroidServerBuilder.java:116)
    at io.selendroid.builder.SelendroidServerBuilder.resignApp(SelendroidServerBuilder.java:125)
    at io.selendroid.server.model.SelendroidStandaloneDriver.initApplicationsUnderTest(SelendroidStandaloneDriver.java:138)
    ... 7 more
```

Although my `ANDROID_HOME` is already set as echoing the commands gives me right path.

```
~ vshukla$ echo $JAVA_HOME
 /Library/Java/Home

~ vshukla$ echo $ANDROID_HOME
/Users/vshukla/AndroidSDK/sdk
```

I am unable to understand as to why this is happening. Please help.

Comment: Are you running from the same shell window where you set it?

Comment: No. I open a new terminal to check the ANDROID_HOME path

Comment: Perhaps it's not set correctly then in the shell you are running from.

Answer (score 0):

it worked for me

1. open to edit /etc/launchd.conf file
2. add the following: setenv ANDROID_HOME /location android_home
3. reboot and it should work.

I hope it helps!!